# WPF C# add text and image to ComboBox during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Basically, when a user clicks a button I would like to add a list of the names of the currently running applications with their icon next to them within a `ComboBox`. I know how to get my list of applications and my icons but am unsure how to link everything together. My XAML for the `ComboBox` currently looks like the following:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="dial1AppSelection" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" MinHeight="25" Height ="25" MaxHeight="35" MinWidth="120" Margin="4,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="dial1AppSelection_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="20" Source="???" />
                <TextBlock ><Run Text="???" /></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add to your combobox

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"
```

2. Create class for your objects:

```
    public class MyProcess
    {
        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; } 
    }
```

3. Add such code to your MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public ObservableCollection<MyProcess> YourCollection { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        YourCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyProcess>();
        YourCollection.Add(new MyProcess() { Image ="image1", Text = "txt1"});
    
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

4. Insert fields names to your xaml code:

```
    Source="{Binding Path=Image}"

    Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
```

Comment: If the Image var is type bitmap should Image be a bitmap instead of a string?

Comment: This implementation worked perfectly for me. The only addition was to convert my bmps to type ImageSource. Thank you!